# Why isn't my background color showing up on <p>?

Tags: html, css

I am confused why the background color is not showing up on this code. There is padding on the `"1"` class but there is no color even though the color is specified. Look in the container class for the problem.

Please help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/*
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
*/

.welcome {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.sub1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 20;
}

.sub2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 20;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}


/*.container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1800px;
    background-size: cover;*/


}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  44% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  89% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  44% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  89% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.container p:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 45s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade 45s 0s infinite;
}
.container p:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 45s 15s infinite;
  animation: xfade 45s 15s infinite;
}
.container p:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 25s 30s infinite;
  animation: xfade 25s 30s infinite;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
}
.1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  /*background-image: url(Pictures/cupcakes.jpg)*/
  
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  overflow: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to JAM Bakery!</h1>
    <div class="slogan">
      <h2 class="sub1">Creamy, Sweet, Toasted</h2>
      <h2 class="sub2">Your Choice.</h2>

      <div class="container">
        <p class="1">1</p>
        <p class="2"></p>
        <p class="3"></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check for any other problems you might see. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

"1" is not a valid CSS class. CSS classes must start with a letter, hyphen, or underscore.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/237955), or [the W3C spec document](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).

Answer (score 3):

CSS class names should not be numeric, and it should start with an alphabet or -(hyphen) or _(underscore)

[The W3C spec on CSS class names](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21
/syndata.html#characters) states the following:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B&W?" or "B\26 W\3F".

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/*
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
*/

.welcome {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', sans-serif;
  font-size: 45;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.sub1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 20;
}

.sub2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 20;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}


/*.container img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1800px;
    background-size: cover;*/


}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  44% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  89% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  44% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  89% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.container p:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 45s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade 45s 0s infinite;
}
.container p:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 45s 15s infinite;
  animation: xfade 45s 15s infinite;
}
.container p:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade 25s 30s infinite;
  animation: xfade 25s 30s infinite;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
}
.t1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px;
  /*background-image: url(Pictures/cupcakes.jpg)*/
  
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  overflow: auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JAM Bakery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Gloria+Hallelujah|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to JAM Bakery!</h1>
    <div class="slogan">
      <h2 class="sub1">Creamy, Sweet, Toasted</h2>
      <h2 class="sub2">Your Choice.</h2>

      <div class="container">
        <p class="t1">1</p>
        <p class="t2"></p>
        <p class="t3"></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```